# Redcloth extend with emoticons filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, emoticons

What would be a good way to implement emoticons/smiley's in a simple messaging system? 
I came out on red cloth as a valuable solution.

The messages will be saved in the DB like ;), :) ;( 
* like described here but this is old: http://flip.netzbeben.de/2008/07/smilies-in-rails-using-redcloth/ I try that any comments on that solution in safety etc?

UPDATE:
Created a helper method , this one works

```
  def emoticons(text)

emoticons = { ":)" => "<img src='/assets/emoticons/smile.gif' class='emoticon'>",
              ":(" => "<img src='/assets/emoticons/cry.gif' class='emoticon'>"
            }

[emoticons.keys, emoticons.values].transpose.each do |search, replace|
  text.gsub!(search, replace)
end

return raw text
```

end

Any way to more improve this? the replacement works although the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
emoticons = {":)" => "[happy/]", ":(" => "[sad/]"}
text = "test :) :("
[emoticons.keys, emoticons.values].transpose.each do |search, replace|
  text.gsub!(search, replace)
end
p text
```

will output

```
test [happy/] [sad/]
```

you can play with `gsub` to get HTML output instead of pseudo BB code

Comment: how would this include an image in the code? its just replacing " ;)" with bbcode? Im investigating red cloth now that seems a better way to go thx

Comment: Like that I misred your answer, I try your idea not sure on how this works for larger textfields and performance when this replace is called a lot but check it out.

Comment: Well got it working with the replacement code Raffaele suggested, if there are any suggestions on how to improve the code